# GROUP BY resulting in undesirable results

Tags: mysql, group-by

In the following query I'm pulling a list of applicants on a specific job. No matter what I GROUP BY, it either gives me the same user but with each different application data or I get 4 rows returned for each.

I've just begun to get into relational database design so I'm assuming I set this up wrong. I split up applicants and applications and now I'm struggling with grouping the data. Unless I just need a subquery, group_concat, or am just using GROUP BY incorrectly?

```
SELECT 
    applicants.*, applications.*, users.*
FROM applicants
    INNER JOIN applications ON applicants.job_id = applications.job_id
    INNER JOIN users ON applicants.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE 
    applicants.job_id = 56 AND applicants.process_level = 1
GROUP BY applications.app_id
```

Table: applicants

```
+-----+--------+---------+--------+--------------------+---------------+
|  id | job_id | user_id | app_id |         applied_on | process_level |
+-----+--------+---------+--------+--------------------+---------------+
|   1 |     56 |     125 |      5 |2015-05-24 19:28:55 |             1 |
|   2 |     22 |      15 |      6 |2015-05-25 16:38:24 |             2 |
|   3 |     56 |     100 |      7 |2015-05-26 13:38:24 |             1 |
+-----+--------+---------+--------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Table: applications

```
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|  app_id | job_id | user_id |   experience |    location |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       5 |     56 |     125 | bibendum jus |     suscipi |
|       6 |     22 |      15 |  Morbi vitae |     aliquet |
|       7 |     56 |     100 | Duis et ex a |   convallis |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

Table: users

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| user_id |      user_email | first_name | last_name |
+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
|      15 |  joes@email.com |        Joe |    Shcomo |
|     100 | sally@email.com |      Sally |     Smith |
|     125 | johnj@email.com |       John |       Doe |
+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Desired Result**: e.g. I want a single row for user 125 where job_id is 56 with all their data from applicant, applications and user. (not all data represented of course):

```
+---------+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
| user_id | first_name |  location | process_level |          applied_on |
+---------+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
|     125 |       John |   suscipi |             1 | 2015-05-24 19:28:55 |
|     100 |      Sally | convallis |             1 | 2015-05-26 13:38:24 |
+---------+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't need a `group by` at all.

Comment: `applicants.*, applications.*, users.*` that doesn't go well with `GROUP BY` and since you are not asking for any aggregate values, you don't really need grouping

Comment: I may have missed it but I'm not sure that you actually say what you are trying to do.

Comment: when you `group by`, all fields present in the select either need to be used in the `group by` clause, or used in aggregate functions (such as `max`). MySQL makes exceptions to this for convenience, but generally if you follow the above you won't get indeterminate results

Comment: Desired results are at the bottom. Might not be clear: 'Desired Result: Individual user with their respective application data' Meaning, row with user 1 with user 1's data from table applicant and application.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff If I don't use GROUP BY, I'm presenting with 8 rows rather than the two I'm looking for.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Sorry. Please see updated table data. job_id was not correct. I want to pull all data where job_id = 56. So i'll have 2 users returned with all of their respective data from tables applicant, applications, users

Comment: If you trace through your expected results, they don't match. Joe's id is 15, not 125.

Comment: @McAdam331 Ugh, yes sorry. I fudged all the data up entering here

Comment: Without the group by, your sample data works fine. You may need to add more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a note on normalization: you shouldn't store job_id and user_id in both the applicants and application table. Likely, you only need them in the 'application' table, since I can go from applicant => application to determine that information. By storing those relationships in two tables, you open yourself up for anomalies that you won't like.

That being said, you don't need to group by anything. There is a consistent relationship between users and applications that you can get using the `JOIN`s you have already. I strengthened these joins by using the user_id, job_id and app_id columns that are related between `applications` and `applicants`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name, a.location, ap.process_level, ap.applied_on
FROM users u
JOIN applications a ON a.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN applicants ap ON ap.user_id = a.user_id AND ap.app_id = a.app_id AND ap.job_id = a.job_id
WHERE ap.job_id = 56 AND ap.process_level = 1;
```

This worked great in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0975c/3).

Comment: That makes complete sense -- and works like a charm. Thanks for your help.